# System Center 2012 location of the updates

Tags: system-center

Hey there we are using System Center 2012 here and im kinda new to it.

The Server downloaded so many patches/updates the Partition where they get downloaded is now full. I cant find the damn option to change the path/drive where the downloads end up.

I already did this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693571.aspx and it transfered a small amount of files to the new partition.

Am i missing something? Can i manually delete and redownload the ones i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is not moving the downloaded updates, it moves the client-installation-packages. You need to move the WSUS storage.

Use the [wsusutil movecontent](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc720466%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) command:

> Changes the file system location where the WSUS server stores update
>   files, and optionally copies any update files from the old location to
>   the new location

`C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\wsusutil.exe movecontent <new content path> <logfile> [-skipcopy]`

Then restart WSUS and IIS.

This should be enough. If you need to move the WSUS database (don't think so), the procedure is much more complex.

Comment: That didnt really help. It only copied a small amount of data to the new partition. The big pile ( probably all the W7 Updates ) are still in the old one.

Comment: @amam Which directory takes up the space and which command did you execute _exactly_?

Comment: M:\Quelle\WSUS takes 15GB

M:\Quelle\update\endpoint takes 90GB

We have an endpoint rollout but i have the feeling the w7 are also inside that endpoint folder cause i downloaded a lot of them some days ago and the folder got a lot bigger

Comment: @amam This really depends on where you installed /configured what, but it seems these are the updates for SCCM Endpoint Protection. If you configure SCCM-EP to use WSUS, the updates should be stored in your WSUS download location. Otherwise you have to move the SCCM-EP updates to a different folder, or maybe just clean up your updates via SCCM.

Comment: I had to delete the Softwaregroup and redo one. Even though i changed the Path somehow it didnt redownload the patches and the other partition.